# Is Ymir Fritz dead or alive in the coordinate?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I suppose of the people in *Attack on Titan* that when they die, they either disappear or go to heaven or hell. But how about Ymir Fritz? She's somehow "alive" in the coordinate, doing things there such as creating titans out of sand. And the coordinate isn't heaven clearly. What's her status there?

Is Ymir Fritz supposed to be dead or alive in the coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, Ymir is def dead. There's no point proving that she's alive.

Now, The Coordinate/The Paths. Now, before we start explaining, there's some things we have to set clear. First, the "parasite that gave Ymir her powers is def some kind of god , it does act like a parasite, lacking onto someone and never letting go,"protecting" them (in some cases, if you get what i mean), and reproduces by their host being eaten, climbing into another host. But it doesn't make sense how it creates demonic-like beings and making daydreams come alive, so my only guess is that it's a parasite.

Alr, now, the Coordinate. The thing that would make most sense is that the Coordinate is a place where users of the titans go after they die/ get eaten, as you can see in the new episode that new branches  grew from the Coordinate when Ymir's body was eaten, and excactly 3. Maybe when a titan user dies , they rest forever in their branch, with ymir being the tree, something like in Death Note, where the Death Note users later become Shinigamis. If you use this theory, then the answer is that Ymir is dead, and her status in the Coordinate heaven is to create titans and do... idk, dead people stuff?

Also, I think that the Coordinate works the same ways for Eldians, since they can all be summoned there , and there are A LOT of branches in the Coordinate... It makes no sense, and i have no idea how it works, but this is my mere theory of it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Ymir is dead with respect to real life . The figure of hers in the coordinate is perhaps a physical manifestation of her soul , more importantly her will to live a life where she is loved by others, the lack of which made her to give up her life in first place . Also a part of her is chained to the paths owing to her unwavering servitude to King Fritz and perhaps , concern , for her daughters and the future lives sprouting from them .
And for Eldians , I believe their souls are transported to the coordinates after their death where Ymir transfers them in a newborn Eldian . Just like titan powers .

Unfortunately , I could not find any cannonical explanations to this question . So we have no choice but to assume things . As we know , the Founding Titan had plethora of abilities , like controlling Eldian biology and memories. So I guess it will be safe to assume that Ymir can also command Eldian souls .

Answer (score 0):

A manga reader here. So, I will take care not to spoil you by this answer, provided you're up-to-date with the anime as of this day. I will be including my own theories and speculations about the path/coordinate as the author, Isayama leaves a lot for the reader themselves to ponder.

First of all, the manga doesn't make any statements about heaven or hell, neither does it make any definite statement about what happens after death. Now, to answer your answer clearly, I will have to explain my idea of the path. Consider path as another dimension where the *souls* of Subjects of Ymir are physically connected to each other via lines of genealogy. It's kind of like a huge family tree, with Ymir as it's starting point. Think of it as record or data of lineage. Hence, once recorded the data exists for all eternity... irrespective of whether the person which corresponds to that data dies in the mortal world or not.

Coming back to your question, Ymir definitely died in our mortal world. But she exists in the path where concept of death doesn't exist, as I explained above.

Tldr; She's dead in the mortal world, but she can't really die in the world of paths.